# USB software to send commands to USB devices from the command line

Tags: command-line, usb

So, I have this HDMI splitter with multiple modes. The software for it can be downloaded [here](https://www.easycoolav.com/products/4k60-hdmi-splitter-1x2-dolby-vision-hdr-scaler-edid-setting-sp12h2). The problem is, not only does the software for the splitter have a GUI, it is also in Chinese. Luckily the HDMI splitter software download also comes with a video om how to use the software so I'm able to navigate it. I was wondering if there is a similar software in English to send commands to USB devices since the software also picks up my Corsair RGB mouse. The software should be for Windows, but I would appreciate if there is a Linux version too so I can also control the splitter in Linux.

What software would be a good CLI alternative with Windows and Linux support to the software provided by the HDMI splitter?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2):

> if there is a similar software in English to send commands to USB
> devices since the software also picks up my Corsair RGB mouse.

Ask yourself, which "USB commands" do you expect to be sent to this HDMI splitter box?

It should be obvious that the box gets controlled with some small microcontroller over a HID-class USB interface (that's why their software also picks on other HID devices). It is highly likely that the set of commands to control the switchbox is proprietary, and is only known to the box designer/manufacturer. So, which "USB commands" would you like to send to it?

Of course, you can try to reverse-engineer the interface, having USB protocol analyzer on the cable, and correlate USB traffic with resulting switch function. Or try to capture USB event trace log (Windows ETL) or some wireshark to understand the command interface. And then write your own driver. Good luck with that.